# Receiving error (Code 52) from a signed driver

Tags: driver, signing, windows-10-iot-enterprise

Sorry about the length but I wanted to get as much detail as I could in.

**TL;DR:** A driver file I signed using `signtool` & Verisign is still giving a Code 52 error when I install it.

I've created an INF file for a device which uses usbser.sys driver file, however even though I've signed it, I'm having trouble installing it on the target machine,   in particular, I'm getting the following error...

> Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

I've created the INF file using a sample file I found here...
https://gist.github.com/tracernz/26a5c4343cec83462fed

I changed it a little but I don't want to paste in my entire file. Here are some of the main points...

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
DriverPackageType = PlugAndPlay
DriverPackageDisplayName = %Device%
Class=Ports
ClassGUID={4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Provider=%Provider%
CatalogFile=myfile.cat
DriverVer=07/16/2016,10.0.14393.0

[Manufacturer]
%Provider% = UsbDevice, NTamd64

[UsbDevice.NTamd64]
%Device% = Usb_Install, USB\VID_2102&PID_0003\5&2E3CC8B3&0&8

[Strings]
Provider = "MyCompany Ltd."
Device = "My Own Device"
```

(I also removed the line `GenericDriverInstalled,,,,1` because INFVERIF was throwing an error because of it and I couldn't find anything online that explained what it was supposed to do or how to fix the error)

Target machine is 64bit Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.

So I create my cat file with inf2cat (`/os:10_X64`) - no errors reported ("Catalog generation complete")

Then I sign the cat file with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool" sign /f ..\MyCertificate.pfx /p MyPassword /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v myfile.cat
```

This is reported as successful.

Then I copy the directory containing myfile.inf, myfile.cat and usbser.sys to my target machine.

On this machine, if I look at the Device Manager, I see my device, but not with the right name `%UNWANTED_CDC_NAME% (COM4)` - I'm not sure where this is coming from. The `USB\VID_2102&PID_0003\5&2E3CC8B3&0&8` in the INF file above is the same as the Device Instance Path for this device.

I run `pnputil \add-driver myfile.inf` and I'm asked by a Dialogue Box whether I trust the publisher, which I agree to, and success is reported.

But in the Device Manager, my device hasn't changed its name to "My Own Device" as I expected!

So I go right click on my device, "Update Driver Software", "Browse my computer for driver software", "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer", "Have disk..." and select myfile.inf

It shows "My Own Device" under the model, and says "This driver has an Authenticode(tm) signature."

But when I click "Next" I get an error saying that "Installing this device driver is not recommended because Windows cannot verify that it is compatible with your hardware." I click "Yes" to continue installing and then "Windows has successfully updated your driver software", but a restart is required.

So I agree to the restart and see my device has the correct name now, but with a yellow exclamation mark. I view the properties and I'm seeing that Code 52 error at the top of this question.

One other detail - I went back then to use `signtool` to verify the signature.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool" verify /v myfile.cat
```

I get a list of certificates in "Signing Certificate Chain" starting with Verisign and a list in the Timestamp starting with Thawte Timestamping CA, but then an error saying:

> SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Is this the cause of the Code 52 error? Why am I getting this, isn't Verisign trusted?

**Edit** - Though if I do

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\signtool" verify /v /pa myfile.cat
```

...I get "Successfully verified"

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10(version 1607),  kernel mode drivers must be signed by Microsoft.
 See also:

- [Driver Signing changes in Windows 10, version 1607](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/)
- [USB serial driver (Usbser.sys)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-driver-installation-based-on-compatible-ids#usbsersys-installation)

> In Windows 10, the driver has been rewritten by using the Kernel-Mode Driver Framework that improves the overall stability of the driver.

I think your driver need to be signed by Microsoft.
I have got same error(Code 52) when I installed driver without Microsoft signature.

Comment: Weird, that first link is gone - I was only reading it the other day...

Comment: @colmde Maybe, first link is same as this. [Driver Signing changes in Windows 10, version 1607](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Hardware-Certification/Driver-Signing-changes-in-Windows-10-version-1607/ba-p/364894)